# Event to detect when user presses "Done" on a full screen video on iOS device through Jquery

Tags: jquery, ios

Is there a way find out if user exits the fullscreen video in iOS device (as in presses Done during video play?

This is what I tried but it didn't work.

```
$('#myVideo').bind('webkitfullscreenchange mozfullscreenchange fullscreenchange', function(e) {
    var isFullScreen = document.fullScreen || document.mozFullScreen || document.webkitIsFullScreen;

    // work with the state flag here...
});
```

Comment: Is it a html5 video player ?

Comment: Yes. Normal `< video>`

Comment: Just check where by default fullscreen event is attached and check for the fullscreenchange of that. Here i guess the full screen event is not attached to "#myVideo" element and so it is not working. Use this script  for it.   var elem = document.fullscreenElement ||
 document.webkitFullscreenElement ||
 document.mozFullScreenElement ||
 document.msFullscreenElement;

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works.

Comment: i guess fullscreen event always binds to document by default !!! Am i right ? Can you share your finding ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check where by default fullscreen event is attached and check for the fullscreenchange of that. Here i guess the full screen event is not attached to "#myVideo" element and so it is not working. Use this script for it.

```
var elem = document.fullscreenElement || document.webkitFullscreenElement || document.mozFullScreenElement || document.msFullscreenElement;
```